# How can I have shared axis labels for an arbitrarily sized grid of subplots in pyplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have seen some answers that get close to addressing what I need to do, but nothing quite like it.

I have a function that produces a variable number of subplots, based on the size of an array that is passed to it. The problem is that, when I try to write the function using subplots(), I can't seem to add shared axis labels. Additionally, the shared x axis tends to be unreadable for large numbers of plots and I'm not sure how to deal with that.

```
def tilePlot(indivArray):
    names = list()
    num_rows = len(indivArray)
    num_cols = len(indivArray[0])
    for r in range(num_rows):
            for c in range(num_cols):
                    names.append(str(r)+str(c))

    f, names = plt.subplots(num_rows, num_cols, sharex='col', sharey='row')

    for r in range(num_rows):
        for c in range(num_cols):

            names[r][c].plot(indivArray[r][c].allValues)
            names[r][c].set_title(indivArray[r][c].name)


    f.subplots_adjust(hspace=.25)

    plt.setp([a.get_xticklabels() for a in f.axes[:]], visible=False)

    plt.show()
```

I tried rewriting the function to use add_subplot, but then I am not sure if there is a feasible way to make the subplots share axes.

```
def tilePlot2(indivArray):
    num_rows = len(indivArray)
    num_cols = len(indivArray[0])

    names = list()
    codes = list()
    counterlist = list()

    counter = 0

    for r in range(num_rows):

        names.append(list())
        codes.append(list())
        counterlist.append(list())

        for c in range(num_cols):
            counter+=1
            names[r].append(str(r)+str(c))
            codes[r].append(c)
            counterlist[r].append(counter)



    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)    # The big subplot


    for r in range(num_rows):
        for c in range(num_cols):

            names[r][c]=fig.add_subplot(num_rows, num_cols, counterlist[r][c])

    # Turn off axis lines and ticks of the big subplot
    ax.spines['top'].set_color('none')
    ax.spines['bottom'].set_color('none')
    ax.spines['left'].set_color('none')
    ax.spines['right'].set_color('none')
    ax.tick_params(labelcolor='none', top='off', bottom='off', left='off', right='off')

    for r in range(num_rows):
        for c in range(num_cols):

            names[r][c].plot(indivArray[r][c].allValues)
            names[r][c].set_title(indivArray[r][c].name)

    # Set common labels
    ax.set_xlabel('Time (s)')
    ax.set_ylabel('RFU')

    fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=.25)

    plt.setp([a.get_xticklabels() for a in fig.axes[-1:]], visible=False)        
    plt.show()
```

I am sorry that my code is inelegant, I am new at Matplotlib. Thank you!